# List's ngrams with zip

Tags: python, sequence

I can make a quick and dirty bigram sequence like so:

```
>>> w = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> zip(w, w[1:])
[('a', 'b'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'd')]
```

I want to make a function that accepts a numerical argument, n, of an n-gram. How do I take that argument and automatically fill in the zip arguments as shown above? In other words, my function:

```
>>> make_ngrams(w, 3)
```

will create

```
>>> zip(w, w[1:], w[2:])
```

on the fly, and return:

```
[('a', 'b', 'c'), ('b', 'c', 'd')]
```

*Can the star operator(s) help(s) me here?* Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
def make_ngrams(lst, n):
    return zip(*(lst[i:] for i in xrange(n)))
```

The `*` operator basically takes all elements of an iterable and feeds them as separate arguments into the function.

Comment: Gaaaah :) I knew the * operator could do the trick! I think I must be done for the day. Many thanks @Volatility! Will accept ASAP.

Comment: Crafty solution (+1), but highly inefficient in terms of space for large `lst` and small `n`

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: definitely, but like I mentioned, "quick and dirty" is all I would be looking for in this case.

Answer (score 2):

```
def ngram(L, n):
    return [tuple(L[i:i+n]) for i in xrange(len(L)-n+1)]
```